# Удалить элемент из массива Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как правильно удалить элемент из массива, если его id = chat_id?
что-то похожее на это, только мой вариант не работает

```
this.dialogs.find((f, idx) => f.id == chat_id).splice()
```

пробовал еще так

```
let el = this.dialogs.find((f, idx) => f.id == chat_id);
el.splice(el.indexOf((f) => f.id == chat_id),1);
```